# I am having a requirement to make my UITabbar to Scroll

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I need a Scrollable UITabbar .I need more than 7 items so I need to make it scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not pretty much sure about this, but I think if you could display UIView or UIViewController in the UITabbar, it will help you to scroll the view present inside this.

Answer (score -1):

if you lay tabbar on the scrollview, you can implement scrollable tabbar.

Adobe method what i explain, maybe one of right methodes. i implement scrollable tabbar adobe method. :D

if wrong my grammar, please understand because i'm not live in englist-speaking countries.